# How to use WHERE IN clause in Android Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to execute an single update query where i have to update a single field for many persons.
Now the below query works :-

```
UPDATE PERSON SET ISSELECTED=1 WHERE ID IN (132,142,115,141,41,133,40,56,139,134,135,65,143,9,64,39,120,104,122,35,19,98,124,127,130,136,119,123,55,102,5,128,140,95,138,131,96,93,129,103,94,89,126,21,29,125,3,101,92,113,4,88,111,63,60,38,114,90,31,118,99,121,117,100,112,97,25,116,10,32,27,30,14,26,12,61,57,20,107,110,91,109,108,106,105,16,62,33,59,18,58,36,11,15,37,28,24,6,7,8,34,13)
```

But it does not return the number of updated rows when used with `execSql` or `rawQuery`

**I am trying to form this query using the `update` method which returns the no. of rows affected**

```
int rowsUpdatedSelected = db.update("PERSON", values, "ID" + " = ?", new String[] {id.toString()}); 
// where id is a StringBuilder object containing the ids like above
```

But this is not working.

Comment: is ID numeric field or text in database

Comment: It is text field but i ran this query in sqlite manager and it updated the data

Comment: Your query ends up as `... WHERE ID = '132,142,115,...'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a method to make IN query string and use that as you selectionArgs. Like below

```
selectionArgs = idArray; // Where id array will be String[] and will contain all of your ids
selection = "ID" + makeInQueryString(idArray.length);
```

Where `makeInQueryString()` is

```
/**
 * Creates where string which can be used for IN query. It creates string
 * containing "?" separated by ",". This method can be used as below <br>
 * ColumnName + makeInQueryString(size) <br>
 * This will create IN query for provided column name.
 * 
 * @param size
 *            size of the items
 * @return IN query string of the form (?,?,?,?)
 */
public static String makeInQueryString(int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (size > 0) {
        sb.append(" IN ( ");
        String placeHolder = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            sb.append(placeHolder);
            sb.append("?");
            placeHolder = ",";
        }
        sb.append(" )");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [sqlite3_changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html) for this:

> This function returns the number of database rows that were changed or
>   inserted or deleted by the most recently completed SQL statement on
>   the database connection specified by the first parameter. Only changes
>   that are directly specified by the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement
>   are counted.

So after your update statement, add this code:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try
{
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT changes() AS updated_row_count", null);
    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        final long count = cursor.getLong(0);
        Log.d("LOG", "no. of updated rows : " + count);
    }
} catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally
{
    if(cursor != null)
    {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is inefficient as i need to update rows and the update method returns the number of rows and the query is fine. I just need to mofidy it according to the `update` method of SQLiteDatabase

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

Put single quote on your in you IN data

```
UPDATE PERSON SET ISSELECTED=1 WHERE ID IN ('132','142','115','14','1');
```

Comment: I want to use the UPDATE method of the database . Raw query is fine and is executing

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this.. just give a try.. and let me know wethr its working or not..

```
int rowsUpdatedSelected = db.update("PERSON", values, "ID IN (?)", new String[] {id.toString()});
```